# How to create a password protected folder in Ubuntu core-16

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-core

I want to create a new folder, in a device with Ubuntu core-16, that is password protected. I am accessing my device over ssh(putty) and since it does not have a GUI, this needs to be done over command line.

Could not find tools like encfs(available for Ubuntu 16.04) for Ubuntu core.

I expect data in a particular folder to be password protected.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28621/351059)

Comment: "Could not find tools like encfs(available for Ubuntu 16.04) for Ubuntu core." There is no software specific to a version of Ubuntu. If there is a encfs for Ubuntu 16.04 then there is one for Ubuntu Core 16.04.  https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/encfs

Comment: I mean, an apt package for encfs must be installed for it to work in an Ubuntu 16.04. But for Ubuntu core, a snap package is required to be installed which I'm unable to find! Please let me know if I've made myself more clear. I'd be happy to know if I'm still going wrong somewhere. :) _/\_